# Codeigniter Postgresql: Transaction with foreign key deadlock

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, postgresql

Im having a problem with a postgresql transaction (with codeigniter), here is the tables involved:

```
CREATE TABLE factura(
nro_factura serial NOT NULL,
fecha_emision date NOT NULL,    
(... more columns)
PRIMARY KEY (nro_factura));

CREATE TABLE detalle(
id_articulo integer NOT NULL REFERENCES articulos(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
nro_factura integer NOT NULL REFERENCES factura(nro_factura) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
(... more columns)
PRIMARY KEY(id_articulo,nro_factura));
```

And this is the transaction:

```
$this->db->trans_start();

        $queryFactura = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO factura (... all columns) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",$factura);

        $id_factura = $this->db->query("SELECT nro_factura FROM factura WHERE id_vehiculo=?",array($factura['id_vehiculo'])); 

        foreach ($articulos as $key){
            $queryFactura = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO detalle (id_articulo,nro_factura,precio_venta,descuento,cantidad) VALUES (?,$id_factura,?,?,?)",$key);
        } 

        $this->db->trans_complete();
```

Now, I cant do the SELECT query because the previous insert has not yet been made. How I can do the second insert without the foreign key from the first insert?

EDIT: 24/06/2014

Finally I used the currval() function of postgre. Only replace the select query for this:

```
 $id_factura = $this->db->query("SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('factura', 'nro_factura'))",array())->result()[0]->currval;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the value of "nro_factura" from the INSERT statement, you shouldn't use a SELECT statement to get it.

PostgreSQL exposes the last number returned by a particular sequence through its [currval() function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html). It's documented behavior is

> Return the value most recently obtained by nextval for this sequence
>   in the current session. (An error is reported if nextval has never
>   been called for this sequence in this session.) Because this is
>   returning a session-local value, it gives a predictable answer whether
>   or not other sessions have executed nextval since the current session
>   did.

CodeIgniter seems to wrap its own function, [$this->db->insert_id()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html), around that PostgreSQL function.

AFAIK, the current versions of every widely used dbms, every ORM, and every database abstraction layer include a function like this.

Comment: Thanks, Finally I use the currval function and it works.